# gettext not retrieving values from .mo file

Tags: php, codeigniter, gettext

I am trying to use the gettext() function to retrieve data I have stored in .mo and .po files.  The problem that I am having is that gettext() seems to just return whatever value I pass it as a parameter, seemingly without using the .mo files.  I am calling the function in a codeigniter controller.

```
class HomeController extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
    global $LANG;


    $language = 'en_US';
    $lang_path = FCPATH.APPPATH.'language/locales';
    putenv('LANG='.$language.'.UTF-8');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $language.'.UTF-8');
    bindtextdomain('lang', $lang_path);
    textdomain('lang');

    $test = gettext('Simpletest');

    echo View::load('layouts/home.html', array(
        'language' => $LANG->getLanguage(),
        'map' => $LANG->get('map'),
        'global' => $LANG->get('global'),
        'page' => $LANG->get('home'),
        'test' => $test
    ));


}
}
```

I have the following directory structure under the 'application' directory.

```
./language/locales/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/lang.mo
./language/locales/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po

./language/locales/fr_CA/LC_MESSAGES/lang.mo
./language/locales/fr_CA/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po
```

my lang.po file in en_US looks like:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

msgid "Simpletest"
msgstr "A small sentence in english"
```

As I said no matter what 'key' I pass to gettext it just returns the parameter i.e. gettext('foo') returns 'foo'.